# cloud based / desktop based open URL load testing tool?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing

I am looking for a cloud based / desktop based free load testing tool which can test direct URLs for up to 1000 VUs and can provide at least 10 minutes of VU load time. I have a website which can be load tested by directly providing the URLs. I dont have enough time and knowledge of load testing to write the script and test my website. Loadimact.com is one of such tools however they charge for more than 100 users.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

- [Siege](https://www.joedog.org/siege-home/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/#/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/)

Siege and Taurus are probably the easiest, however others offer record-and-replay functionality and JMeter has GUI, see [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) for description, comparison and sample load tests with results.